# How to plot a week interval in X axis using c3js?

Tags: d3.js, axis, intervals, c3.js

I want to plot a graph with c3.js library that displays a week interval in x axis as the picture below:
[image]

I have a JSON file that has several dates in it that I would like to use:

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    "date": "2016-09-20"
},
{
    "foo": 2,
    "date": "2016-09-21"
},
{
    ...
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would have made this is a comment, however I cannot, so my recommendation would be to create this line graph using d3.js not c3.js. Here is a really good tutorial [Setting up axes in d3.js](http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/setting-up-axes-in-d3js.html) that will generate the above chart and you can customise the x axis to what ever you want. [weekly x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKsED.png)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer for this question.
My JSON data has a field called "weekDetails", that contains a string with the week interval, like "Sep 22-28" for each register. With this information in mind, i have to call a function like below to load the json and specify the key value for X axis, that is "weekDetails"

```
chart.load({
    json: myJson,
    keys: {
        x: 'weekDetails',
        value: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
    }

});
```

After that, you have to change the property x: to 'category' in c3.generate() function, like below:

```
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category'
    }
}
```

And my json file would be like:

```
{
    "foo": "foo",
    "weekDetails": "Sep 1-7"
},
{
    "foo": "foo",
    "weekDetails": "Sep 8-15"
},
{
    "foo": "foo",
    "weekDetails": "Sep 16-23"
}...
```